# Error in Yuen test code

Tags: r, statistics, robust

I am trying to perform a Yuen's robust test on R but I am having an issue with the following error code:

```
Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula
```

I have used the following packages and code:

```
library(WRS2)
library(car)
library(akima)
library(MASS)
library(robustbase)
library(rrcov)
library(scatterplot3d)
library(trimcluster)
library(parallel)
PremS <- c(0.06,    0.02,   0.04,   0.03,   0.03,   0.01,   0.04,   0.02,   0.07,   0.05,   0,  0.11,   0.04,   0.02,   0.03,   0.03,   0.04,   0.01,   0.06,   0.03,   0.02,   0.03,   0.03,   0.02,   0.02,   0.03,   0.02,   0.02,   0.04,   0.03,   0.03,   0.03,   0.02,   0.04,   0.06,   0.03)
PremR <- c(0.04,    0.02,   0.05,   0.02,   0.04,   0.02,   0.01,   0.01,   0.02,   0.04,   0,  0.02,   0.01,   0.01,   0.01,   0.03,   0.02,   0.03,   0.02,   0.02,   0.02,   0.01,   0.01,   0.04,   0.01,   0.03,   0.03,   0.03,   0.02)
yuen(PremR,PremS,tr=0.2)
```

If anyone is able to help, I would be extremely grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in order to call function `yuen`, you only need to load package `WRS2`. The others are a bit too much.

Now for the question. You need to call the function with an object of class `formula`. Like this:

```
yuen(PremR ~ PremS,tr=0.2)
Error in model.frame.default(formula) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'PremS')
```

Now the error thrown is different.
So I've checked the lengths of the two variables.

```
length(PremS)
[1] 36
length(PremR)
[1] 29
```

You now need to correct your data.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate that

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not getting the same error as you. I am getting : Error: unexpected symbol in "yuen(PremR ~ Prem S"

Comment: Do you now why this is?

Comment: @DanielRawlings Because you have a typo in `Prem S`: there's a blank space before the `S`. Remove it and you'll have the error I've got.